# Update Fragment view inside viewpager without data reloading

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-xml

[image]

How to reload the viewpager after click on submit button(as shown in image) but not the data inside listview because it comes from server due to which it takes time

Comment: Put data from server in local db, reload from db..?

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a singleton class. 
2) Create a parameter in that singleton class like *isDataLoaded*.
3) When you downloaded the data use MySingleton.getInstance().setIsDataLoaded(true).
4) Bind the data downloading to that parameter in Fragment A like

```
if (!MySingleton.getInstance().getIsDataLoaded())
    downloadData();
```

After doing this, even when the Fragment A is recreated, the data will not be downloaded.